# Subscripted value not array nor pointer

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

I have a program that reads a 2d array from a file, and makes it a jagged array (where each row is sized perfectly to fit all non-zero elements).  Then it prints the array out.

But I have a couple issues I can't figure out.

Specifically

> 26: I get a warning (assignment makes integer from pointer without cast
>
> 44: error: subscripted value is neither array not pointer

What can I do to fix it?

```
int main() {

FILE *inputFile1 = fopen("denseMatrix1.txt", "r");

char inputBuffer[SIZE];
int dim1, dim2, input, i, j;
int *mtrx1;

fgets(inputBuffer, SIZE, inputFile1);
sscanf(inputBuffer, "%d%d", &dim1, &dim2);

mtrx1 = malloc(sizeof(int *) * dim1);

for (i=0; i<dim1; i++) {
    int cols=0;
    int *row = malloc(sizeof(int) * cols);
    fgets(inputBuffer, SIZE, inputFile1);
    for (j=0; j<dim2; j++) {
        sscanf(inputBuffer, "%d", input);
        printf("i=%d   j=%d    input=%d\n", i, j, input); // ADDED LINE (NOT PRINTING)
        if (input) {
            cols++;
            row = realloc(row, sizeof(int) * cols);
            row[cols-1] = input;
        }
    }
    mtrx1[i] = row;
    cols=0;
}

int mtrx3[DIM1][DIM2] = {0};

// Prints first 2 matrices
printf("First matrix: \n");
printMatrix(mtrx1, dim1);/*

return 0;


// Prints a 2d array matrix
void printMatrix(int *mtrx, int dim1) {
int i, j;
for (i=0; i<dim1; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<(sizeof(mtrx[i]) / sizeof(int)); j++) {
        printf("%d ", mtrx[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("\n\n");
```

Contents of file denseMatrix1.txt:

```
7 8
0 0 0 5 1 0 0 5
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 2 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 5 0 0 3 0
1 0 0 0 0 3 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: this code doesn't compile and there are several errors in the syntax, for instance the '\*' at the end of this line: printMatrix(mtrx1, dim1);/*  and even if that error were not there, the closing '}' at the end of the main() function is missing, as is the remainder of the printMatrix() function

Comment: the returned values from the I/O input functions (scanf, fgets) need to be checked to assure the desired operation actually occurred.  the format string for the scanf() will fail due to white space still being in the input (for instance the newline).  To fix that, there needs to be a leading ' ' in the format string

Comment: if the call to realloc() fails, then the next line of code will cause a seg fault event.  I.E. test the returned value before using

Comment: the variable 'input' is not defined.  Did you even try to compile this code?

Answer (score 1):

In stead of

```
int *mtrx1;
```

use

```
int **mtrx1;
```

With the former declaration, `mtrx[i]` evaluates to `int`. You need it to evaluate to `int*` to be able to use:

```
mtrx1[i] = row;
```

**Update**

Your strategy of using `fgets` to get a line of text and using the line of text with `sscanf` is not going to work in a `for` loop.

Let's take the first line of the matrix:

```
0 0 0 5 1 0 0 5
```

and the `for` loop:

```
for (j=0; j<dim2; j++) {
    sscanf(inputBuffer, "%d", input);
    printf("i=%d   j=%d    input=%d\n", i, j, input); // ADDED LINE (NOT PRINTING)
    if (input) {
        cols++;
        row = realloc(row, sizeof(int) * cols);
        row[cols-1] = input;
    }
}
```

In the `for` loop, you will end up `0` being assigned to `input` every time for the first line. `sscanf` does not store what you read the first time and continue from what's left.

You'll need to come up with a different strategy. For example:

```
for (i=0; i<dim1; i++) {
   int cols=0;
   int *row = malloc(sizeof(int) * cols);
   fgets(inputBuffer, SIZE, inputFile1);
   char* token = strtok(inputBuffer, " \n");
   for (j=0; j<dim2; j++) {
      input = atoi(token);
      printf("i=%d   j=%d    input=%d\n", i, j, input);
      if (input) {
         cols++;
         row = realloc(row, sizeof(int) * cols);
         row[cols-1] = input;
      }
      token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
   }
   mtrx1[i] = row;
   cols=0;
}
```

Comment: The new strategy makes sense, but I get warnings regarding making assignments without casts.  Also it still won't print out the printf.  Don't really know what else to do, but I am required to use sscanf.

Answer (score 0):

## Line 26 Warning

Here is the line in question:

```
mtrx1[i] = row;
```

And here are the declarations for these variables:

```
int *mtrx1;
int ..., i, ...;
int *row = ...;
```

As your warning message says, you are trying to take a pointer value, `row`, and assign it to an array of `int`s. Assuming that what you want is `mtrx1` to be an array of individual `row` sub-arrays, you should change its type accordingly – from `int *`, which is an array of `int`s, to `int **`, which would be an array of *arrays* of `int`s.

## Line 44 Error

Relevant code:

```
void printMatrix(int *mtrx, int dim1) {
    int i, j;
    ...
    printf("%d ", mtrx[i][j]); // line 44
    ...
}
```

The error on this line is the result of a problem similar to the one above – `mtrx` is declared as a one-dimensional array of `int`, but in line 44 you have two subscripts as if it is a two-dimension array. This is also fixed by changing the type of `mtrx` to `int **`.

## For Loop

The `for` loop is failing to iterate over all values because your `sscanf` line is ambiguous – there's no space between your `%d` values, and so `sscanf` can't tell which number should be which, and it reads them through as one value. This means `dim2` is never properly set.

For this sort of bug, using breakpoints is the usually the easiest way to get an idea of what's going on in the program, particularly for loops. If you haven't looked into them yet, you should.

## Additional Info

Line 26 gives you a warning while line 44 gives you an error because of the way pointers are defined in relation to ints in C. C allows for "pointer arithmetic," which means pointers can be treated as plain numbers in addition to referring to objects or arrays.

When you subscript an array in C, the type of the expression effectively just drops a `*`; for example, subscripting a `int *` array has a type of `int`. So when you try to assign a pointer to `int *mtrx1`, it treats it like trying to assign a pointer to an `int` variable, and so the pointer gets converted to its raw numeric value. This is perfectly legal C, but is considered by most programmers to be fairly bad practice (for various reasons), and so the compiler gives you a warning for it.

Line 44 is sort of the opposite case – your `mtrx[i][j]` expression is equivalent to `(mtrx[i])[j]`. Since `mtrx` is defined as just a `int *`, this means you effectively end up trying to subscript an `int`, which is flat out illegal in C. No warning, just an error.